# How to search for multiple types with Google Places API in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to search for more than one type with the Google API for an iOS app.

here's how I search for one type. In this example it's of type **museum** I'd like to search both **museum** and **art_gallery**. How would I go about doing that in:

```
NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=**museum**&sensor=false&key=APIKEY"];
```

thanks for any help

:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had added two request parameters and i am getting response which contains both atm's as well as cafe's.
You can refer the below link to validate the response.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=19.148279,72.993874&rankby=distance&types=cafe|atm&sensor=false&key=

Answer (score 5):

You can enter more than one type by modifying your request parameter types=museum|art_gallery add more types separate by | operator

Comment: I thought that and tried the following without any success: &radius=500&types=museum|art_gallery&sensor=false&key=

Comment: This works completely fine for me and yields the desired results. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=34.0522222,-118.2427778&radius=500&types=museum|art_gallery&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE

Comment: types is now deprecated